# ODE with exponent

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$y'=xe^{x+y}$$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=xe^{x}e^{y}$

$\frac{dy}{e^y}=xe^{x}dx$

${e^{-y}}dy=xe^{x}dx$ integrating both parts:

${-e^{-y}}=xe^{x}-e^x+C$

${e^{-y}}=e^x-xe^{x}+C$ taking $ln$

$-y=ln(e^x-xe^{x})+C$

$y=-ln(e^x-xe^{x})+C$

Are all the steps correct? is there a shorter way?

Comment: **Hint:** It is Separable, try multiplying each side by $e^{-y}$.

Comment: @Moo yes Just did that and added to the question

Comment: Looks good - you can leave the constant inside the log term.

Comment: More specifically you **MUST** leave the constant inside the log term: $$y=-\ln(e^x-xe^x+C)$$

Comment: Or in the same way $e^{-y}=e^{ln(e^x-xe^x+C)}$ so $-y=ln(e^x-xe^x+C)\rightarrow y=-ln(e^x-xe^x+C)$

Comment: That works - and is correct (you can easily check your result by subbing it in to the ODE).